# PhpExcel: how to emulate excel's dragging of cell contents

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm writing a PHP script to generate excel reports through use of PHP excel. What I would like to do is allow users to specify that the contants of cells can be 'dragged'. By this I mean to make use of or emulate that feature of excel that allows the user to select one or a number of cells and drag their contents in order to generate the contents of adjacent cells. I cant find any information on this. Would I need to generate the cell's contents in my script or is there some sneaky feature of PHP excel that can do this for me? I would assume the former but I'm very new to PHPExcel so want to make sure before diving in.

Comment: How do you want to implement this? Do you want to allow the user to do this in a HTML table? Where do you want the "dragging" to take place and how is the user interacting with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "sneaky" features of PHPExcel, you have to set the content for each cell, but there are a couple of methods that can help setting several cell values in a single call.

If you're talking about straight data content you can specify a start cell and pass an array of values to the Worksheet's fromArray() method:

```
* Fill worksheet from values in array
*
* @param  array   $source                 Source array
* @param  mixed   $nullValue              Value in source array that stands for blank
*                                             cell
* @param  string  $startCell              Insert array starting from this cell
*                                             address as the top left coordinate
* @param  boolean $strictNullComparison   Apply strict comparison when testing for null
*                                             values in the array
* @throws Exception
* @return PHPExcel_Worksheet
public function fromArray( $source = null, 
                           $nullValue = null, 
                           $startCell = 'A1', 
                           $strictNullComparison = false
                         )
```

If you need to manipulate formulae across a range of cells, e.g. =$A1+$B1+$C$1 for a set of rows so that $A1 and $B1 become $A2 and $B2 for the second row, $A3 and $B3 for the third, etc, then the ReferenceHelper's updateFormulaReferences() method may be useful:

```
* Update references within formulas
*
* @param   string  $pFormula    Formula to update
* @param   int     $pBefore     Insert before this one
* @param   int     $pNumCols    Number of columns to insert
* @param   int     $pNumRows    Number of rows to insert
* @return  string  Updated formula
* @throws  Exception
public function updateFormulaReferences( $pFormula = '', 
                                         $pBefore = 'A1', 
                                         $pNumCols = 0, 
                                         $pNumRows = 0, 
                                         $sheetName = ''
                                       )
```